# How to export my vagrant local VM to a VM which is on my company server?

Tags: windows, vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, virtualbox

I have a VM with vagrant working on local, but I have to put it on the server of the company wich gave me access to a VM. I can access to this VM thanks to SSH but how to transfer my local vagrant VM instead ?

I am working on windows and the VM are on Ubuntu

Thanks

**Vagrant file :**

```
    # -*- mode: ruby -*-
    # vi: set ft=ruby :
    require "./source.rb"

    ROOT_PATH = File.dirname(__FILE__)

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

def configure_extra(config)
end

def configure(config)
  config.vm.box = "trusty64"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 8000, guest: 8000
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 9001, guest: 9001

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # If true, then any SSH connections made will enable agent forwarding.
  # Default value: false
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  config.vm.synced_folder "./data", "/home/vagrant/data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    # Boot with headless mode
    vb.gui = false

    host = RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os']

    # Giving a quarter of system memory to VM and access to all available cpu cores
    if host =~ /darwin/
      cpus = `sysctl -n hw.ncpu`.to_i
      # sysctl returns Bytes, converting to MB...
      mem = `sysctl -n hw.memsize`.to_i / 1024 / 1024 / 4
    elsif host =~ /linux/
      cpus = `nproc`.to_i
      # meminfo returns KB, converting to MB...
      mem = `grep 'MemTotal' /proc/meminfo | sed -e 's/MemTotal://' -e 's/ kB//'`.to_i / 1024 / 4
    else
      # hardcoding values for windows...
      cpus = 2
      mem = 1024
    end

    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", mem]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", cpus]
  end

  # Provisioning
  config.vm.provision "shell" do |shell|
    vagrant_shell_scripts_configure(
      shell,
      File.join(ROOT_PATH, "scripts"),
      "provision.sh",
      {}
    )
  end
end

# Look for a Vagrantfile.local to load
local_vagrantfile = "#{__FILE__}.local"
if File.exists?(local_vagrantfile)
  eval File.read(local_vagrantfile)
end

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  configure config
  configure_extra config
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vagrant itself prepare the VM locally (network, IPs, etc and so on) but this is already configured in the VM provided by your company. What I usually do is to run the scripts (for instance sh) directly in the external (or real) VM. You can also install some provision tool (puppet for instance) in the VM and run the scripts included in your Vagrantfile. If you can post the Vagrantfile here, this would help a lot.

Comment: thanks, 
So I have to importe my vagranFile on the real VM ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand, my project is in taiga-vagrant file of my local VM. Do you think it will work to import this file + the vagrant file on the real VM ?

Comment: No, the Vagrantfile is used to create the local VM in VirtualBox. As I mentioned before you need to execute directly the shell commands in the external VM created. This is the key part in the Vagranfile -> File.join(ROOT_PATH, "scripts"), "provision.sh", which i suppose includes the steps to install taiga. Copy the scripts/provision.sh file to the new VM and execute it (maybe it needs some pre configuration)